# Print different text from the same variable in excel

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have a spread sheet in excel / google sheet (link below)

[google sheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kw9JLNBDlWtqyWqvySVhBtz4Hz7oiPn6/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=109626011108852110510&rtpof=true&sd=true)

The problem is :

There are two columns: 1) for id and 2) some text related to the id

I want to print all the unique texts (concatenate like) from the same id number in a another cell.

Any help who I can do that?

I have tried vlookup but does not work.

Hypothetical example is the below table

| VAR1 | VAR2 | RESULT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | ONE |  |
| A | TWO | ONE,TWO |
| B | THREE |  |
| B | FOUR | THREE,FOUR |
| C | FIVE | FIVE |
| D | SIX | SIX |

[image]

Comment: Your file is blocked, it says *Unauthorized Error 401*. Also, note is not the same Excel than Google Sheets, so I strongly suggest to use just one tag, not both of them. Besides, an example of the expected output would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not literally the same as your required solution, but it will produce a distinct list of values in Var1 and associated comma-separated values from Var2 (alphabetical), Google Sheets only:

```
=arrayformula(({A1:B1;to_text(split(regexreplace(flatten(split(textjoin(",",1,query(query(if(A2:A<>"",{char(9999)&A2:A&char(9998),B2:B,B2:B},),"select Col1,Min(Col2) group by Col1 pivot Col3",0),"where Col1 is not null",0)),char(9999))),",$",),char(9998)&",",0))}))
```

[image]

**UPDATE**

Stress testing the formula results in an issue after about 5000+ rows since the `textjoin` function can only contain 50000 chars.

An alternative solution is this (var 2 can be text or numbers):

```
=arrayformula({A1:B1;regexreplace(substitute(query(substitute(split(flatten(trim(query(transpose(query(if(A2:A<>"",substitute({A2:A&char(9999),B2:B,B2:B}," ",char(9998)),),"select Col1,Min(Col2) group by Col1 pivot Col3",0)),"",9^9))),char(9999))," ",","),"where Col2 is not null",0),char(9998)," "),"^,",)})
```

It still works with 15000 rows. Var 1 is made up of IDs between 0001 and 1000. Var 2 has up to 10 different options:

[image]

Comment: YES IS GOOD but I do not have 4 ids.I have 10000?what changes I have to make in order to work for all my ids?

Comment: The formula should just work with the content available. However, my test sheet only seems able to process 5774 rows. The limit is perhaps the query pivot. I'll see if there's another way.

Comment: are there equivalent formulas as your answer for excel ?

Comment: Updated solution. The initial limit is the `textjoin` function only being able to process 50000 chars.

Comment: IN EXCEL FORM ?

Comment: I no longer use Excel since it doesn't have functions like regex, arrayformula or query. You might be able to use power query, but I'm not familiar with it. Sheets seems to have the edge in my opinion.

Comment: UNDERSTOOD.Anyway thanks for your help and your answer.My issue with google sheet is that this file that I want to implement your function has 550.000 rows! and g sheets cannot deal with so many rows

Comment: If your data is at rest (without any dynamic updates), perhaps look at BigQuery to do the processing?

Answer (score 1):

In `google-sheet` try below formula-

```
=IF(A2<>A3,JOIN(",",FILTER($B$2:$B$7,$A$2:$A$7=A2)),"")
```

[image]

Comment: If I have more than 2 texts related to an id from VAR1 ? for example 5 texts? I want the unique texts to be printed not all the texts.

Comment: Then use Unique function `=IF(A2<>A3,JOIN(",",UNIQUE(FILTER($B$2:$B$7,$A$2:$A$7=A2))),"")`.

Comment: It does not work because id has more than 2 replications.So if I autofill the IF(A2<>A3) produces NA in columns 500-505 for example.And in the second condition in filter function.